# preg_match dot and slash

Tags: php

I would like to add a regular expression character dot `.` and such a slash `/`.

```
    'numericString' => array(
        'pattern' => '^[a-zćęłńóśźżA-Z0-9\s]+$',
    )
```

**How i can do?**

Comment: A note: aside from normal escaping with your hardcoded regexes, when dealing with user supplied content `preg_quote` is your friend.

Comment: are you sure that you want to associate that pattern to something called numericString???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add `\.` and `\/`

```
'numericString' => array(
    'pattern' => '^[a-zćęłńóśźżA-Z0-9\s\.\/]+$',
)
```

Comment: Noneed to escape the `.` inside `[]`

Comment: @Michael yes u are, but no harm doing it

Comment: no need to escape the `/` either, if it is not the regex delimiter

Answer (score 1):

***Note***: you must escape the characters "^.[$()|*+?{\" with a backslash ('\'), as
they have special meaning.

Use the below code..

```
'numericString' => array(
'pattern' => '^[a-zćęłńóśźżA-Z0-9\s\.\/]+$',
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

A literal `.` is expressed in a regex as `\.`

A literal `/` is expressed as `\/`

Note: not all regex flavours require escaping the `/`, only the ones that use it for delimiting the regex.

Comment: I think in range expression you don't need to escape the dot ?